# Can I help my kitten regrow fur after being affected with ear mites?

Tags: cats, grooming

I have a persian kitten, and he has earmites,  I am just about to buy some ear cleaner, but I think it also affected the growth of his fur (it was lesser and shorter), can you recommend me anything to make his fur grow back after I remove those earmites?

Comment: The fur damage is probably just from scratching, and should solve itself once the mites are gone.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, a vet should see your cat and prescribe an ear cleaner that kills or repells the mites. Ear mites are extremely uncomfortable and itchy and they are also contagious. If you have several pets, you'll have to treat all of them preventively to stop the mites from migrating from one pet to the next.

While at the vet, you can ask them for food supplements that aid hair growth. Our dog once had an oily food supplement that made the fur absolutely soft and shiny.

The hair loss is caused by the cat scratching his ears and can occur at the back of the ear or on the cheeks in front of the ear. A home remedy is to gently apply castor oil or olive oil to the hairless skin. This will prevent the skin from drying out and softens the scabs that form as a result of the mites biting the skin, making them easier to remove.